# does it matter where i put a hidden field in an html page?

Tags: html, form-submit, hidden-field

To get additional ID information (like the page name) about the page when it's submitted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be within the form. It doesn't matter where, unless you do something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text"   name="data[]" value="value1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="data[]" value="value2" />
  <input type="text"   name="data[]" value="value3" />
</form>
```

In this case the `data` array isn't associative, so the position of the elements does matter.

Similarily, if you'd traverse your POST / GET data with a foreach loop without paying attention to the array keys, you could get problems (but if you have an associative array, you should use the associations, especially in user input).

---

I mention these things just to make the answer more complete. In most cases the simple answer applies - position of hidden fields does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't matter, as long as it is within the form.

Answer (score 1):

No. Values from an HTML form are mostly treated as being an associative array. To that end, the order in which the elements appear are of hardly any concern.

Answer (score 0):

It matters in the sense that the order of data fields in submitted form data normally corresponds to the order of fields in HTML markup. You can see this easily if you use the default method (GET), so that the fields will appear in the URL.

There is no requirement on this; it is just how browsers tend to behave. Any robust form data processing does not count on any particular order.

I have sometimes observed browser rendering oddities that seemed to depend on the placement of hidden fields. It sounds weird, because hidden fields should not affect rendering.